Unable to read data to the transport connection
I get the following error

Unable to read data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The search is either closed by the server or has some errors and there are a few ways to fix it, but it still doesn't work
When I call using Packet Sender, it's still normal
Debug has an error in stream.ReadAsync, the rest is normal

the code
// call TCP 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

byte[] ByteASCII_1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AsciiPayload);

TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ZgwIP, TCP_DIAG_PORT);

NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

await stream.WriteAsync(ByteASCII_1, 0, ByteASCII_1.Length);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1048];
int countByte = 0;

string stringHex = string.Empty;
while (stream.CanRead)
{
    int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    //string hexResponse = CryptoHelper.ByteArrayToHexString(buffer, bytesRead);
    //stringHex += hexResponse;
    //countByte += bytesRead;
    //if (countByte >= 74)
    //{
    //    break;
    //}
}
RTB_Logs.AppendText($"\n{stringHex}\n");
tcpClient.Close();
stream.Close();

I tried with Packet Sender at the same time with that error, and it worked without error, which means there is a problem with my code.
I added
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

but not successful

use
SslStream clientStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream())
When you want to get data in tls
but you may get error because you are not using ssl certificate so in one of parameters in ssl stream you should set false for checking client certificate

And maybe your problem is for timeout
set reciever timeout to the time higher than you set before

The another thing is that maybe remote host is wating for message and you did not send anything in that timeout period
